# MySql Workbench parameter placeholders

Tags: mysql, editor, workbench

While browsing through the available snippets in the workbench I came across pieces of code with sort of formal parameters and/or placeholders, in the form of `<{[identifier]}>`, which are particularly highlighted in the editor .

Are they simple formal placeholders or do they have some other additional use?

Comment: Does this help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/named-parameters-in-mysql-workbench-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are placeholders and they are designed to make your snippets less specific and more general purpose. You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> to automatically move to the next placeholder to fill in the specific values you need.

For example:

```
    /* find total sales for each product, including only products that have total sales exceeding a specified amount */
    SELECT
        Products.ProductName,
        SUM(Orders.Quantity) AS TotalSales
    FROM
        Products
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID
    GROUP BY
        Products.ProductName
    HAVING
        SUM(Orders.Quantity) > <{[minimum_order_amount]}>
```

You can load this snippet into the editor, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> to automatically move to the variable that you might want to edit. You can have as many of these placeholders as you like.

**Note:** the shortcut key combo only works *forward.* Once you are below a placeholder, the shortcut won't find your placeholders. So if you paste a snippet, you'll have to move to the top of your snippet (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd>, for example).